# how to search for a string pattern in the current file and list the occurrences with lighttable?

Tags: lighttable

I would like to search for a string pattern and also get the list of occurrences below it in the light-table.

I can search the whole work-space and get the list for me of the occurrence but how do I do it for a single file?

in a single file search, how do I get the list of occurrences after my search in the current file editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'find bar' searches the current editor tab. The 'searcher', by default, searches all of the files in the current workspace.

There's no way to do this with the find bar, but with the searcher, you can restrict the files searched to just one file – just replace the default *<workspace>* with the (full) path of the file you want to search.